# Why don't the build result directories start ** in VS .gitignore

Tags: git, visual-studio, gitignore

There's a standard Visual Studio .gitignore file available [here](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/VisualStudio.gitignore).

It includes this section:

```
# Build results
[Dd]ebug/
[Dd]ebugPublic/
[Rr]elease/
[Rr]eleases/
x64/
x86/
bld/
[Bb]in/
[Oo]bj/
[Ll]og/
```

Why don't those lines start with the [gitignore pattern format](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) `**/` so that the search includes all subdirectories?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Relative paths (as your directory names) already *are* ignored everywhere.

If you create a structure

```
foo/
  bar/x.txt
bar/x.txt
```

(where x.txt is just fluff to have non-empty directories)

and have a .gitignore file containing just

```
bar
```

then git is ignoring both `bar` directories.

Absolute paths like `/bar` would only ignore a top-level directory instead.
Are you sure that you're seeing a different behavior?

The documentation you linked to contains this:

> Two consecutive asterisks ("**") in patterns matched against full pathname may have special meaning:
>
> A leading "**" followed by a slash means match in all directories. For
>   example, "**/foo" matches file or directory "foo" anywhere, **the same
>   as pattern "foo"**. "**/foo/bar" matches file or directory "bar"
>   anywhere that is directly under directory "foo".

(emphasis mine)

Comment: So does `foo/bar` differ from `**/foo/bar`?

Comment: No, both matches a file or directory (you need a trailing slash if you're only talking about directories) ```bar``` below ```foo```.